# How to draw Windows-style folder icons that preview the contents

Tags: c#, wpf, thumbnails

I have a C#/WPF application that displays collections of components. I want to know how to create an image that is styled like the Windows 7 folder icon, where one or two of the content thumbnails are enclosed by a yellow leaf folder. (The collections I have aren't real Windows folders, and their contents aren't real Windows files)

[image: Examples]

### Google Approach

I have spent a fair amount of time searching for code samples on how to do this, or anything even remotely similar. I can't find a single example of anyone doing this, which has truly surprised me. It tells me one of two things:

1. I can't find the right keywords to search on (combinations of: thumbnail, windows, c#, wpf, icon, folder)
2. Nobody else has ever wanted to do this, and that's because there is a better way of doing what I want to do.

### Coding Approach

I can see that there might be a back image drawn first, and then skew transforms applied to each content thumbnail, overlaid, and then finally the front image. I've seen some code examples that show how to skew images, etc. There are some very subtle effects being drawn here too (shadows), though they could be "canned". I'm not sure how to separate the example images below into a front and back portion, though I could give it a try in Photoshop.

### Windows API Approach

The closest approach I've been able to find without coding this from the ground up is to write a component's thumbnail to a real Windows .PNG file, inside a real folder, and then use Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetThumbnailAsync() to get Windows to do it for me. Obviously this makes me die a little inside, but it might be the quickest way to do this.

---

Can anyone help me? Ideally I am looking for a library or existing code sample that could show me how to generate these. Otherwise, I will attempt to code this myself using the coding approach outlined above. I'm not looking for someone to write this code for me, but I would appreciate any pointers.

Thank you!