# Set folder display thumbnail in Explorer with C#

Tags: c#, thumbnails, explorer

Is there a way to set the property Explorer uses to display a folder thumbnail in code?  Which interface do I need to use to set it?

I don't mean the icon displayed, I mean the thumbnail shown for the directory when for example Extra Large Icons is selected, such as below.  The UI in explorer allows the user to select an image.  I would like to do it with C# if possible.

Presumably there's a Shell interface somewhere?

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question (still unanswered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059106/how-to-draw-windows-style-folder-icons-that-preview-the-contents. Best regards,

Comment: Interesting, thank you Alex.

Comment: You are welcome. I guess, there is no simple solution, but the question is rather interesting: voting up. best regards,

Comment: I wondered about it years ago. Failed to solved id dough.